# Can anyone explain this sql query clearly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Query will exclude weekends. In the query:

1. What is the `* 2` doing in `(DATEDIFF(wk, Startdate,Enddate) * 2)`
2. Here Saturday how it will be minus (Saturday not mentioned) 
   `(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Startdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`
3. Here how Sunday will minus (Sunday not mentioned) 
   `(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Enddate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

In date diff(wk,startdate,enddate)*2) here how weekends finding and excluding exactly.

I am thinking like( 20 days-(20/7=2.6*2=5.8(Round to 6)-0-0) briefly(20-6-0-0= 14 days) is correct. but how it exactly identifying  sat and sun.
I am correct or not. My question is why multiplying with 2 why can't with 3 or 4?

Query is working correctly. I am missing things in the query to understand.
Please see the query and explain clearly.

```
SELECT
    Startdate, Enddate,
    (DATEDIFF(dd, Startdate, Enddate)) -
        (DATEDIFF(wk, Startdate, Enddate) * 2) -
        (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Startdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -
        (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Enddate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS workingdays 
FROM
    EMP_Table;
```

Comment: Please only tag a *single* RDBMS - I have removed the conflicted tags.

Comment: The *2 is because for any week, there are 2 days of weekend.

Comment: Btw: This is an absolutely dangerous approach, if your code will ever run on a system with a different culture/language...

Comment: The algorithm is flawed.  StartDate '20191012' and Enddate '20191013' would return -1 working days.  StartDate '20191012' and Enddate '20191014' would return 0 working days even though 2019-10-14 is a Monday- and a working day.  Most likely there are other examples of unexpected behavior as well.

Answer (score 0):

Line by line:

First get the raw number of days between the dates:

```
(DATEDIFF(dd, Startdate,Enddate))
```

Subtract the number of weekend days, which will be the number of weeks times 2

```
-(DATEDIFF(wk, Startdate,Enddate )*2)
```

Adjust for the case where the start date is a Sunday

```
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Startdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Adjust for the case where the end date is a Saturday

```
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Enddate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Why not mentioned "Saturday" in Start day and Why not mentioned "Sunday" in Enddate

Comment: Its to do with the datediff function and where the week boundary is. Saturday is last day of one week, Sunday is first day of next week. @prasanthkumar

Answer (score 0):

As pr [DATEDIFF()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp)  will return the `difference` between two date by given interval,

and
[DATENAME()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datename.asp) will return specific part of the date which here `dw` will return `weekday` it may any day of week like `Sunday`, `Monday` etc

Now Execution of Query:

For example:

`Startdate='2019/10/6'` and `Enddate='2019/10/12'`

`DATEDIFF(dd, Startdate, Enddate)` will give `6`

`DATEDIFF(wk, Startdate, Enddate)` will give `0` and  there are `2` days of `weekend` so `0*2=0`

`CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, Startdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` will give `1` because it's a `Sunday` and same as for `Enddate` it's a `1` due to `Saturday`

So final equation is `workingdays=(6-0-1-1)` so it give result as `workingdays=4`

Comment: my question is it should minus day-day-day-day but your explanation day-week-day-day like this.

Comment: actually here `DATEDIFF(wk, Startdate, Enddate)` this will return  total number of difference  in `week`. and you have to find `workingdays` every week has 1 `Sunday` and `Saturday` so `total number of sat-son`  is `weekday* 2`